# Change value of one field in SSRS depending on another field

Tags: reporting-services, null, ssrs-2012

I have a report in SSRS with the following values:

```
    Location   Primary   State
    Hospital       Y       TX
    NULL           Y       TX
```

I'm trying update the report so that if Location is null, then Primary and State will also be Null.

I've tried using this expression in the State text box, but it doesn't work:

```
    =IIF(IsNothing(Fields!location.Value), "", Fields!state.Value)
```

Is there another way to solve this?

Comment: try testing the length of location instead. This will overcome empty strings as opposed to null/nothing.
 `=IIF(Len(Fields!location.Value) = 0, "", Fields!state.Value)`

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you!